# VC++2008 project always "out of date"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

In one Solution, I have two VC++ projects.  Project A has linker inputs that are .obj files compiled by project B.

Visual Studio (2008) **always** tells me that project A is "out of date," and prompts me to ask if I want to rebuild it, every time I want to run/debug/build/etc.  Even immediately after building the entire Solution: I do a successful full build, and then click Build again, and it wants to re-link Project A.

How can I prevent this from happening?  Anyone understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the solution is to stop using .obj files from the other project. Instead, factor the code that is common to both A and B projects into own static library C and link both A and B to it.

Comment: I'd be willing to accept that, if only I could understand **why** using the .obj's doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @user406289: Does your solution have a dependency set between A and B? Maybe your are building the projects in bad order?

Comment: Yes, there is a dependency defined in the Solution, and I've also confirmed in the Build Order that B is supposed to build before A.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem with **Visual Studio 2010** (both with and without SP1) and thanks to [Ted Nugent](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/38c08137-3bb0-4143-b97f-72d077646318) I was able to fix it. The trick is to check whether all C++ header files listed in the project still exist, and remove the non-existing ones. Apparently this is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: If I read your link correctly, that problem is specific to VS2010.  It sounds like it's related to the fact that C++ projects are built with msbuild in VS2010, which wasn't the case in VS2008.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! I came across this post trying to solve the VS2010 issue. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Had something similar occur. I was working with code that used the system time and during the debug I was twiddling with it quite a lot. Somehow the files got some bad timestamps. In the build, it shows which files are getting recompiled, so I just opened each, forced a change (add space, delete a space) and then re-saved.

Similar to the old unix "touch".

In one project I had to do the same to its include files. But after 'touching' the files like that, the problem went away.