# VC++ projects keep being out of date

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution which contains both C# and C++/CLI projects. My problem is that the C++ projects are always out of date, and the IDE keeps asking if I want to build them.

There are some custom build steps, which copy some files here and there, and I suspect that might cause the issue (?). I'd be fine with disabling up-to-date check for these projects (if there's no other way), because they are not going to be modified for now. How can I do that?

Please note, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371713/vc2008-project-always-out-of-date) is very similar, but not a duplicate.

Comment: I always have problems when I have a C++/CLI project referencing a C# project.  Seems like no matter what I do, the C# project always trips the C++/CLI one into rebuilding, even if nothing changes.  I have not yet found a fix for it.  Maybe you're running into the same problem?

Comment: Maybe, but unfortunately I did not find a solution either. Well, I did upgrade my dev machine since, so it's much less annoying now :)

Comment: Ok turned out it wasn't the C# project's fault.  I had a non-existent header file referenced in my C++ project, and that's what was causing the rebuild.  Apparently that's a bug in Visual Studio.  You might check for any of those.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether during build (or post build) tasks, you change a dependency, which determines (of course) a new, fresh build.

Another possibility is that you mentioned as part of the custom build task, a dependency that doesn't really exist (e.g. an external file with the wrong name or path).